# What does "disabled echoing" means?

Tags: java, console

> The `readPassword()` method of the
>   `Console` class has echoing disabled.

What's echo?

Comment: Just FYI: This kind of question is best answered by a very short script:  
    Console cons;
    cons.readPassword();
    cons.readLine();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means you can't see the characters while you are typing in the console. As you would normally do.

This way you can ask for a password on the commandline but nobody can read by eavesdropping on your computer screen.

This is the equivalent of a password textfield in the GUI world where you see stars `*` instead of the actual characters.

Answer (score 3):

It means it doesn't show what the user types, like when you type a password at Linux login.